# vlc does not display via vlc-wrapper but cvlc works after 22.10 upgrade

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video, vlc, 22.10

After upgrading from 22.04 to 22.10, `vlc-wrapper` no longer displays dvd video content (sound works).  However, and oddly enough, running `cvlc` works.

I am under x11 rather than wayland because of another software requirement. I am using the 470 driver set of NVidia (unchanged from 22.04) using a Geforce 1030.

The upgrade from 22.04 to 22.10 was uneventful, everything else works (including basic opengl checks).  I poked around online but no suggestion, apart from one that suggested `cvlc` may work.

The error message suggests I am lacking

```
$ vlc-wrapper Videos/some_mp4_file_recorded_on_my_phone.mp4 
VLC media player 3.0.17.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[000055c362a95550] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[00007fe8bc0049c0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
libva info: VA-API version 1.15.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007fe8bc0049c0] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.15.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
[00007fe8b8098690] main video output error: video output creation failed
[00007fe8ccc7a220] main decoder error: failed to create video output
[00007fe8bc0049c0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007fe8ccc7a220] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  470.161.03  Wed Oct 19 00:03:46 UTC 2022 for hardware decoding
```

With `cvlc`  I get

```
$ cvlc Videos/some_mp4_file_recorded_on_my_phone.mp4 
VLC media player 3.0.17.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[0000561a244132c0] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[00007f4170004b10] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
libva info: VA-API version 1.15.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f4170004b10] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 1.15.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
[00007f4180001b40] main video output error: video output creation failed
[00007f4188c79d80] main decoder error: failed to create video output
[00007f4174001720] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f4188c79d80] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  470.161.03  Wed Oct 19 00:03:46 UTC 2022 for hardware decoding
```

I am reasonably familiar with package.ubuntu.com to search, but at a loss about `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so` -- which package would provide this?

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem. did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: Sadly, no.  I just got by with `cvlc` and it is a genuine regression in  Ubuntu 22.10 to me.

Comment: I found out that kaffeine (also installed in my box) works in my case, so I'm using that for the moment; incidentally, I also have an nvidia card in my box (well actually it's a laptop with built-in intel and nvidia graphics card)